# how to strip a subkey from a gpg key?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I am trying to remove the subkey from my OpenPGP key.

Here is the current state:

```
gpg> uid 1

pub  3072R/C08D1F4B  created: 2014-01-05  expires: never       usage: SCEA
                     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  3072R/97AFAF8E  created: 2014-01-05  expires: never       usage: SEA
[ unknown] (1)* Vivarto (Banana) <vivarto@gmail.com>
```

So, there is a primary key, and a subkey:

```
pub  3072R/C08D1F4B  created: 2014-01-05  expires: never       usage: SCEA
sub  3072R/97AFAF8E  created: 2014-01-05  expires: never       usage: SEA
```

I'd like to have only the first part

```
pub  3072R/C08D1F4B  created: 2014-01-05  expires: never       usage: SCEA
```

I tried `deluid`, but got *"You can't delete the last user ID!"*

Comment: This is exactly by deleting the subkey. OpenPGP implementations will (by default) choose the newest key capable of the operation desired; if there is no subkey, the primary key will be used. The usage flag show what the key can be used for: S for signing, C for certifications, E for encryption and A for authentication. Your primary key is capable of doing everything, but the subkey will be used if available.

Comment: take care before deleting a subkey it can break things https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262703/deleted-a-subkey-and-can-now-no-longer-decrypt/

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to delete a user ID, not a subkey. Use `key [n]` and `delkey` instead. From the `help` comand inside `gpg --edit-key`:

```
uid         select user ID N
key         select subkey N
deluid      delete selected user IDs
delkey      delete selected subkeys
```

If you already shared your key with others, better *revoke* the key instead of deleting it. By deleting it, other's will not be able to realize you're not using it any more (you can't delete it on key servers and other's computers!), by revocation you're signalling "don't use this (sub)key any more".

Though, before deleting the subkey, read some words about key management ([[1]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29851/how-many-gpg-keys-should-i-make/29858#29858), [[2]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31594/what-is-a-good-general-purpose-gnupg-key-setup/31598#31598), and I especially recommend [Debian's notes on subkeys](https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys?action=show&redirect=subkeys)).

Comment: **is there any way to issue a single command to do all of this: **

1. edit key 
2. keyname 
3. key 
4. delkey 
5. y(es) 

Or is it necessary to do in through the interactive mode necessary?

Comment: I don't know of any other way but the interactive mode.

Comment: Follow-up questions in comments with different topics/not aiming at clarification are discouraged in the stack exchange network. Better ask a new password (and also consider having a small peak at the manual/man pages of GnuPG).